# Key already registered with the same priority: GroupSpatialSoftmax

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I get this error:
"Key already registered with the same priority: GroupSpatialSoftmax"
when i run:

```
    import torch
```

Though I've installed the pytorch package through the pycharm settings > python interpreter.
Does anyone know how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Solved it myself!
I uninstalled the pytorch package and re-installed it so now it works

Comment: This is not the proper way to answer the question. Give an explanation or follow StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: I had torch-1.10.2+cu102-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl installed. Everyting was working fine. It started to fail after install torchvision for this version "pip install -Iv torchvision==0.11.3". So I uninstalled the torch, and installed again and magic is done... why? don't know, something wrong during torchvision installation.